# Arrays Unidimensional

Tags: programacion-asincrona

tengo problemas con mi programa es en java, la idea es leer un archivo y que guarde lo que contiene el archivo en un array, lo que sucede es que quise poner todos los n en un arrayn con longitud 24, y parece ser que esta creando un array por c/u

```
            //Lee el archivo                                  
            
            //Declaracion de variables
            String  no = scan.next();
            String[] arrayn = new String[24];               
                                           
            while (!n.equals(".")) {                                       
               
                n = scan.next();     
                for(int i =0; i<arrayn.length; i++){

                arrayn[i] = n;
                System.out.println(arrayn[i]);
        }   
                //imprimir solo una posicion
                System.out.println("posicion3: "+arrayn[3]);                   
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que se ve es un **for** dentro de **while** que se encarga de cargar el dato leído en *arraynombre*, lo que hace es cargar el cada iteracion del bucle while el dato leído en **todas** las posiciones de *arraynombre*.

Es decir en la primera iteracion de while todas las posiciones de arraynombre es'alto', en la segunda: 'BR' y así hasta el final.

```
  //Array del nombre
    for(int i=0; i<arraynombre.length; i++){
           arraynombre[i] = nombre;                   
    }
```

Comment: entiendo lo que me explicas, solo que me aparece el siguiente error `traductor.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraynombre));
                                           ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class traductor`       derivado de la linea de codigo `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraynombre));`

Comment: Si es una utilidad para imprimir arrays, necesitas hacer el importe para que funcione ' import java.util.Arrays; '

Comment: Ah ya, cuando imprime al final el array fuera del while, por ultimo pone null, deduzco que el while guarda hasta el 24, y como el 24 es FIN, se lee el archivo hasta que encuentre fin, y la posicion 24 es justamente fin, cierto @LucasRox?

Comment: Si, es lo que pasa, 'FIN' no lo guarda  porque se cumple la condición para que termine el while. Si es necesario guardar fin hay que cambiar el momento en que lee los datos

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias @LucasRox lo marcare como solucionado!